# How to bypass an Internet connection that only allows access to FB and twitter

Tags: firewall, internet-connection, bypass

On my connection I can access FB and twitter only. How do I work around to gain access to other websites.

The browser is not locked or something, Its my own laptop that am using.

Comment: What do you get when you try to access some other site?

Comment: Be interesting if someone wrote a IP-over-Twitter tunneling proxy.

Answer (score 0):

VPN will most likely let you access the rest of the web. Download [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) for your platform and set it up by using a free service, such as [VPNBook](http://www.vpnbook.com/) (Click on the OpenVPN tab and download any of the bundles. Then import any of the profiles inside).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free online proxy service such as [HideMyAss!](https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/) This requires no installation.

Another method would be to use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), although this may be a little overkill for your situation.